# GET ID_ROW from SQLITE DB in the AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

How i can get a ID_ROW from the Database?

**AlertDialog**

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

        switch(id){
        case MENU_1:

            builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("TITLE");
            builder.setAdapter(scAdapter, null);

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(scAdapter, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROW_ID:"+which,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
        return null;
  }
```

But which - is not a ROW_ID(SQLITE) , it's a position number.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to call `scAdapter.getItemId(which)`. If it's a cursor adapter, it will give you back the value of the _id column. If it's a custom adapter, you will probably need to override the getItemId() method to get the data you want.